Can I get timedelta between first and last metric from prometheus?
For example I have Gauge my_metric.
my_metric{job="1"} 1.0 - at 13:00 - first
my_metric{job="1"} 1.0 - at 13:10
my_metric{job="1"} 1.0 - at 13:20 - last

How can I get timedelta from first to last metric? I need to get 13:20 - 13:00 = 20 minutes.
I tried to do.
I got timestamps for each metric:
timestamp(my_metric))

Than I tried to get delta:
delta(timestamp(my_metric)))

but have an error:
bad_data: invalid parameter "query": 1:7: parse error: expected type range vector in call to function "delta", got instant vector

If i try to get range vector from timestamp:
delta(timestamp(my_metric))[1h])

I have an error:
bad_data: invalid parameter "query": 1:67: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors


You can try using PromQL subquery with increase function:
increase(
  timestamp(my_metric)[30d:1m]
)

This method has the following drawbacks:

It may return incorrect results because of extrapolation in increase() function.

It may be slow because Prometheus calculates subquery results per each step interval, where step is the duration, which goes after the colon in square brackets (it equals to one minute (1m) in the query above).

The lookbehind window in square brackets must cover the whole time series, including the first and the last raw sample. If this isn't the case, then the returned results will be lower than expected.


P.S. There is a lifetime() function in MetricsQL - this is PromQL-compatible query language I work on. This function can simplify calculating time series' lifetime.
